# AngularJs Form Model Not Submitting via Ajax

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter

I can't get the values of the form passed via ajax. I used angularJs model. Please help. My codes below.

for hmtl:

```
<form role="form" ng-submit="submit_new_rpo(new_rpo)">
              <div class="box-body">    
                <table class="table table-striped"> 
                  <tbody> 
                    <tr>
                      <td>RPO# :
                     <input type="text" 
                       class="form-control" ng-model="new_rpo.po_number" required="required">
                     </td>  

                    </tr>

              </div>
              <div class="box-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
              </div> 
            </form>
```

Ajax:

```
$scope.submit_new_rpo=function(rpo)
    {  

      $http({
                method : "POST",
                  url : burl + "po/insert_po_manual" 
                  ,data:{"rpo":rpo}
              }).then(function(response){ 
                  alert(response.data);
              }, function myError(response) {
                  $scope.err_content=response.data;
                });
    }
```

php

```
public function insert_po_manual()
    {

        $params = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);
        if(!isset($params))
        {
            show_404();
        }

        echo $params['rpo']['po_number'];
    }
```

I am getting empty array in my server. I used the code in other modules and its working.But this time I don't know why Im getting empty values.

Comment: when i code alert(rpo) it shows empty. But when i code alert(rpo.po_number) it works. But what i want is to get the array variable to pass it just once and not by individual field.